# WebView wrong encoding, please suggest

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have a webview that's supposed to show cyrillic text

```
wv.loadData( myStringHtml, "html/text", "utf-8");
```

But here's what I'm getting. :) Any ideas? Should I use a different encoding?

[image]

Thanks!

***EDIT:
Fixed it by using loadDataWithBaseURl***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to know a ton about Cyrillic encodings, but I've forgotten exactly which that is. Either way, my suspicion is that the source data isn't actually in UTF-8. [This tool](http://2cyr.com/decode/) gives ought to help in figuring out which one you've got.

Comment: hmm, not exactly, server appears to be giving in utf-8. probably its something with the webview.